# simple binding problem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I have a rather simple problem, but I am unable to get my head around it...
I have a class that inherits from `UserControl`. It has an `AxisColor` DependencyProperty of type `Color`. In the XAML structure of the class I have `<ms3DTools:ScreenSpaceLines3D Thickness="2" Points="0,0,0 100,0,0"  Color="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=AxisColor}"`.
The binding does not work. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: are you setting your data context correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a UserControl that needs to get a Property `AxisColor` from a class, you need to set your DataContext of that UserControl to the class that contains AxisColor.

```
myUserControl.DataContext = myClassInstance;
```

Otherwise, your user control does not know where to grab the property from.

Comment: Thanks, this worked...
One more question: Is there an equivalent for this in XAML?

Comment: I guess I'm confused. I thought you said that the 'AxisColor' property was defined on the UserControl class itself. Did you just do 'myUserControl.DataContext = myUserControl;'?

Comment: or more simply: MyUserControl.DataContext = this; ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` to the binding expression. Otherwise, you are binding to the DataContext property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want UI binding then you have to specify [ElementName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx), more options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746695.aspx). If you want data binding then make sure you have DataContext set up correctly.